# python program not working apt-get install xvfb

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, pycharm

i'm trying to run a program that i downloaded but it isn't working
pycharm returns the following

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fb-hfc.py", line 291, in <module>
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(1600, 900))
  File "/home/apple/.local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 33, in __init__
    self._obj = self.display_class(
  File "/home/apple/.local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 51, in display_class
    cls.check_installed()
  File "/home/apple/.local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 38, in check_installed
    ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()
  File "/home/apple/.local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 180, in check_installed
    raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self)
easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Program install error! 
You can install it in terminal:
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

running apt-get install xvfb doesn't help

the app is fb-hfc google it you'll find it if its code help

Comment: I'd suggest this is a better fit for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: What happens when you run it on a python in terminal/console/whatever (and perhaps with virtualenv to see what packages it needs).

Answer (score 0):

type this command:

```
pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay
```

or this command:

```
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```